# IIS rewrite set 301 redirect

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

i want these url redirect.

example 1:

http://wwww.old.com/News/List
to
http://wwww.new.com/News/List

example 2:

http://wwww.old.com/News/List?page=1&type=2

to

http://wwww.new.com/News/List?page=1&type=2

example 3:

http://wwww.old.com
to
http://wwww.new.com

my setting below

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="site2.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://wwww.old.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://wwww.new.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Don't make common mistakes, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{HTTP_HOST} should match `wwww.old.com` instead of `http://wwww.old.com`, you can change the `rewrite` to `redirect`, this rule you can use as a reference:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$" />          
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^wwww.old.com$" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://wwww.new.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```